# How to configure DbMigration of EF not to add Datetime as prefix of generated migration file name

Tags: entity-framework, app-config, entity-framework-migrations, dbcontext, nuget-package

When I run `Add-Migration ABC` into package manager console, it create a file name 201508210357164_ABC. File name contains a datetime prefix, I don't want this prefix.

How can I stop adding datetime prefix while running `Add-Migration BCA` everytime.
or
How can I choose prefix myself such 'dbname' instead of datetime while running `Add-Migration BCA` everytime.

Comment: Why do you want to do that, time stamp is actually helping you, it defines the order in which migrations needs to be updated

Comment: I want to manage it by myself, the ordering of migration

Answer (score 0):

An important pat of migrations in EF6 is the ordering of Migrations, so there is no way to change this